# The idemix part of the hyperleger fabric contains two methods, NewNymSignature and NewSignature. What is the difference?

Tags: go, cryptography, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I found these two methods in the idemix directory of the fabric project while learning idemix.
From the name point of view, these two methods are to sign the message, and will use NYM, do not know what their difference is：

```
func NewSignature(cred *Credential, sk *FP256BN.BIG, Nym *FP256BN.ECP, RNym *FP256BN.BIG, ipk *IssuerPublicKey, Disclosure []byte, msg []byte, rhIndex int, cri *CredentialRevocationInformation, rng *amcl.RAND) (*Signature, error)

func NewNymSignature(sk *FP256BN.BIG, Nym *FP256BN.ECP, RNym *FP256BN.BIG, ipk *IssuerPublicKey, msg []byte, rng *amcl.RAND) (*NymSignature, error)
```

Comment: Hi painter Qiao, please try and always include the language / runtime environment within the question in a tag, if just to automate the syntax highlighting. This will also give more exposure to your question. Is this a [tag:c] question?